# What do we call a point in a triangle where the length from it to the other vertices are equal?

Tags: geometry, triangles, triangle-centres

I tried a lot of research and I still can't find it.

So what do we call the middle point where the length from it to the other vertices are equal?

Here's a diagram.

[What we need to find out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHIyZ.png)

Does anyone know what the point is called? Is it the orthocenter, circumcenter, or centroid? Or is it something else?

Comment: It’s the [circumcentre](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMAT6680Fa05/Evans/Assignment%204/Assignment%204.htm); note that it can lie entirely outside the triangle.

Comment: So technically assuming the circumcentre is O, that means OA = OC = OD, right? Because that's what I'm trying to find out.

Comment: Where $A,C$, and $D$ are the vertices of the triangle? Yes, if $O$ is the circumcentre, then by definition $|OA|=|OC|=|OD|$.